# How can I access nested JSON object in Django Template properly?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm trying to access some info with dot notation but I'm getting a weird error. I'll try to explain as well as I can with my code.

My relevant code from views.py file:

```
def index(request):
    // removed "x" assignment as it is long an irrelevant
    month = (datetime.datetime.now()).strftime("%B")
    year = str(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    customers = table(x, month, year)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'customers': customers, "month" : month, "year": year})
```

Here, I call my tablequery file with table function to return a JSON object of files I have from MONGODB(I am not using MONGODB as the default DB so I do it manually). My table function is as follows:

```
def table(user, month, year):
    ///// Code to access DB removed
    curs = col.find()
    list_curs = list(curs)
    liststring = json.dumps(list_curs)
    liststring = re.sub("_", "", liststring) // have to remove _ from "_id" because template doesnt allow "_id" type of variable to be used with dot notation
    jt = json.loads(liststring)
    return jt
```

Type of "jt" appears to be "list" in python when I print it.

My relevant html code:

```
<tbody>
    {% for customer in customers %}
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>{{ customer.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.isim }}</td>                                                             
            <td>
                {% for ekran in customer.ekranlar %}
                    <li>
                        {{ ekran }} DENEME
                        {{ customer.ekranlar.1.hesapbakiyeTL}} TL
                        {{ customer.ekranlar.1.yurtdisibakiyedolar}} USD
                        {{ customer.ekranlar.1.yurtdisibakiyeeuro }} Euro
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </td>                                                            
            <td>{{ customer.temsilci }}</td>
            <td>
                <li>{{ customer.toplambakiyeTL }} TL</li>
                <li>{{ customer.toplambakiyeUSD }} USD</li>
                <li>{{ customer.toplambakiyeEURO }} EURO</li>
            </td>
            <td>  </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'delete' customer.id month year %}" class="btn ink-reaction btn-floating-action btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Müşteriyi tamamen silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?')"><i class="md md-delete"></i> </a>
                <a href="{% url 'edit' customer.id month year %}" class="btn ink-reaction btn-floating-action btn-warning"><i class="md md-edit"></i> </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Problem lies within the second for-in loop. When I write "ekran" in customer.ekranlar, I only get the "1", "2", "3" etc as output, but not the values for those. There are more variables within those nested objects(? maybe not objects) but I can only access them if I do "customer.ekranlar.1.hesapbakiyeTL" but when I do "ekran.hesapbakiyeTL"(because I need them looped an printed in table cell) I dont get anything because "ekran" is only "1" or "2" or whatever else the name of the "ekran" is but not the values inside.(I have 4 different accesses as tests to see what is visible how, so it's not the final form)

What I think it should be is like I said, "ekran.hesapbakiyeTL" should be able to access that value, but "ekran" only gets the key, not the nested keys/values inside it. I tried so many different things, tried to change the tablequery output type but I get different problems that way, tried to us "forloop.counter" to use as index to access directly as "customer.ekranlar.forloop.counter" but it appears variables cannot be used in dot notation and many others I've forgotten in the last week. Please, I've been stuck trying to access those values within the for-in loop which stops me from going forward with my project and add other functions.

An example document directly from MongoDB Compass app:
[Image for data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMRWy.png)

Blues: float numbers
Blacks: strings

There can be more in "ekranlar" as in 1, 2, 3...
All help is appreciated.

Thank you all and have a good day

edit1: I tried to get nested values seperately from python. Same things happens. As soon as I use a second for loop to access like "{{ for ekranlar in customer.ekranlar }}, I only get the key values, not the other variables or their content inside

edit2: How I got around it is that I created a custom tag and sent the customer info to a python file in templatetags with forloop.counter and returned needed info that way. Feels a little clunky but works so meh... If anyone gets around to why this happens inside template html, I'd still love to hear it.

Comment: this is just my opinion, but I tend to transform my raw data in my view so that it's easily usable by the templates. That way you avoid all of these problems, and you can use python to do data transformations, which IMHO is nicer than dealing with nested data in the templates.

Comment: I tried to pass forward different types of data, but only numpy array and this worked for other variables, yet still no access to data with the nested loop. I can access the data through "customer.ekranlar.1.kurum" for example. But when I do "for ekran in customer ekranlar" and use "ekran.kurum", it doesn't work. All I get is "1" without the data it holds with the second loop. Any suggestions on how to loop through the nested data within views? Because some customers have only 1, some have up to 5 nested objects(?) with multiple variables within so I need to loop them in the table cell